# Still get error popup even when ApplyUpdates is inside try...except

Tags: delphi, odbc

**Solution found, see my comment below**

D5, odbc to mysql database

This code:

```
  with QryCmdPerf do begin
    Close;
    ParamByName('ACCTID').AsInteger:= AcctId;
    ParamByName('FROMDT').AsString:= MySQLDate(FromDt);
    ParamByName('TODT').AsString:= MySQLDate(ToDt);
    Open;
    first;
    try
      edit;
      FieldByName('PnL').AsFloat:= 97979;
      ApplyUpdates;
    except
      close;
    end;
  end;    // with
```

(specifically the "ApplyUpdates") causes a popup to appear with the text "Update Failed" if the PnL field already has the value 97979, evidently because of this code:

```
procedure TUpdateSQL.ExecSQL(UpdateKind: TUpdateKind);
begin
  with Query[UpdateKind] do
  begin
    Prepare;
    ExecSQL;
    if RowsAffected <> 1 then DatabaseError(SUpdateFailed);
  end;
end;
```

in DBTables.pas.  Anyway, I want to be able to issue ApplyUpdates, and not have to worry about a popup if it doesn't do any updating.  But if "try...except" doesn't work, what will?

TIA

Comment: nevermind, discovered "OnUpdateError" handler in TQuery, if it's set to something, the "Update  Failed" popup doesn't appear.  I guess that's one way to force people to use the OnUpdateError handler...

Comment: Dave, if that answers your question, then please add it in the *answer* section. That's where other people will look when they come here with the same problem as you.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't let me answer my own question, it tells me new users (which I evidently am) cannot answer their own questions

Comment: Ah, you're right. There's an 8-hour waiting period for users with less than 100 reputation points. ([That's a new rule, as of April 9.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange))

Comment: Here's the "answer your own question" msg I got: New users can't answer their own question for 24 hours. Please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: [The "24 hours" message is a bug.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88257/33732) It's really 8. Please add your solution. It's the correct answer.

Comment: FYI, just added it ("The short answer is..."), but I couldn't check it (i.e., as "the solution") because when I tried I got a popup saying "You can accept your own answer tomorrow."

Comment: Also, thanks for the SO "tutorial", I'm at 62 pts, I can comment everywhere -- woohoo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you have to set up an eventhandler for OnUpdateError or no amount of "try...except" blocks will block the popup.  The long answer is it appears to be a bug with odbc.  The repro is here: http://www.codeupload.com/3919  for anyone who wants to take a look at it.  You can skip the MySQL stuff, any odbc database will do.

Comment: +1 Small correction, this is **not** an ODBC issue. It's an issue with `TBDEDataSet`. You should be able to get the same problem with BDE Native Paradox. `TBDEDataSet.CachedUpdateCallBack` will under certain conditions short-circuit the exception stack to call `Application.HandleException`. This is a dodgy way to handle exceptions, which are supposed to be allowed to unwind the call stack. Is it a bug in `TBDEDataSet`? ... well, it has been implemented that way by design, so even though it is strange, unconventional and hence unexpected - it wouldn't really be classified as a 'bug'.

Comment: Interesting.  I couldn't reproduce it without ODBC -- I tried using the DBDEMOS tables that come with D5, and the same code (trying to update a numeric field with the value it already had) ran without a hitch.

Comment: As I said, there are certain conditions to `TBDEDataSet.CachedUpdateCallBack` short-circuiting the unwinding of the call-stack. But that is where the problem lies - not ODBC. Compile with Debug DCUs. Put a break-point in `TBDEDataSet.CachedUpdateCallBack` and with a variety of tests you'll be able to confirm the specific conditions of each scenario. Also, if you implement an `OnUpdateRecord` event handler that simpler raises EDatabaseError, you should get the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing the dialog displayed by *the debugger* with a dialog displayed by *your program*. Please see this article I wrote a few years ago:

- [Why do I continue getting error messages even after I have written an exception handler?](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exception-messages)

It describes several ways to avoid the debugger interfering:

- Use "advanced breakpoints" to temporarily disable the debugger around the code that throws exceptions.
- Configure the debugger to ignore certain exception types. (Read the debugger's message more carefully to see exactly what exception class you're dealing with.)
- Configure the debugger not to interrupt on any exceptions.
- Turn off integrated debugger entirely.

Comment: See also, [How do I let Delphi know I've already handled an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234950/how-do-i-let-delphi-know-ive-already-handled-an-exception)

Comment: +1 Oh yes! Sometimes you become so familiar with a concept that you forget its existence. :) This is a very common misunderstanding with beginners.

Comment: Actually, I've been working with Delphi for over 10 years now, and I do know the difference between running an exe in the IDE and running it outside the IDE.  I tried getting the error to occur without odbc and mysql, but I couldn't, so my guess is there is something peculiar about odbc and/or mysql that when you attempt to update a field with a value that it already has, the problem I described above occurs.  Here is a reproduction: http://www.codeupload.com/3919.  Remember, you have to update the numeric field with a value it already has, or it'll just do the update.

Comment: @Craig: I am not a beginner, please set up the repro I provided before you assume you've seen every bug Delphi has to offer.

Comment: @CraigYoung and @RobKennedy, if you'd like to skype into my machine to see, that's fine, we can set something up thru stackoverflow chat, I'd guess

Comment: Great news!  The repro is even easier: you can just use an ODBC text file (Microsoft Text Driver), and get the same phenomenon: a popup resulting from ApplyUpdates, even when ApplyUpdates is in a Try...Except block (and yes, OF COURSE, running the exe standalone when the Delphi is closed). So it's clear that it's an ODBC thing, not MySQL. C'mon, guys, is it truth you're after, or just SO reputation points?

Comment: If I were really after reputation, I would have taken your comment and posted it as an answer because I've checked the VCL source and confirmed that *DBTables.pas* calls `Classes.HandleApplicationException` if `OnUpdateError` isn't assigned, and that displays the exception dialog. I'm leaving it for *you* to answer so that *you* can get the points; 50 and 100 points are important thresholds here, and I don't wish to stand in your way.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Very gracious, Rob, I apologize for doubting your integrity. Would it makes sense to edit your original post to reflect your recent research?

Comment: @davej: You misunderstand me, I'm not in any way implying that _you_ are a beginner. However, Rob's answer is a very common pitfall for beginners. And while that's not the case in this particular instance, many beginners are likely to struggle with similar problems. Seeing this answer will likely help them out, so it fully deserves my +1. Furthermore, I know from first-hand experience the VCL's (especially Db, DbTables & DBClient) tendency to lean towards dodgy exception handling practices. I didn't need to investigate the specfics, because you'd already solved this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that can be going wrong here.

#### Option 1

First, some "very bad code" may be short-circuiting the unwinding of the call stack on exceptions. E.g. `ApplyUpdates` or one of its child routines may also have a `try...except` block that calls `Application.HandleException` directly.

To test this, if you put a breakpoint on `QryCmdPerf.Close`, do you reach it?
If not, then `Application.HandleException` (or worse `Application.ShowException`) has been called directly.

Solving this requires a custom exception handler hooked to the Application.OnException event. You may have to set temporary state to know when this particular exception can be ignored.
Yes it's messy, that why calling `Application.HandleException` directly, is "very bad code".

#### Option 2

If you do reach the breakpoint, but the exception is being raised again, then it should be a lot simpler to solve.

The `Close` method is probably attempting to save any pending changes, so is effectively applying the updates again. Rather than simply closing the data set, call `CancelChanges` or equivalent.

Comment: I do reach the "close', but it's AFTER the popup, that is, if I put a breakpoint on ApplyUpdates, then step (f8), I get the popup, click its "ok" button, and then the debugger goes to the next line, the "close" in the "except" clause.  Anyway, as I put in my comment to the original post, the popup can be eliminated if one utilizes the "OnUpdateError" handler, even with just dummy code.  Thanks for your efforts, tho.

Comment: I got curious as to why you'd still hit the `QryCmdPerf.Close` breakpoint after the 'short-circuit' to `Application.HandleException`. `TBDEDataSet.CachedUpdateCallBack` is called by one of the BDE DLLs. If an `EDatabaseError` is raised (you can easily force it in the `OnUpdateRecord` event handler), then `Application.HandleException` is called and `DBIERR_UPDATEABORT` is returned to the DLL. Which in turn passes that back into `TBDEDataSet.ApplyUpdates`, and ultimately raising an EAbort (silent) exception.