# Exception not catching inside try..except statement

Tags: delphi

I have the following code:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetFolderDate(Folder: string): TDateTime;
var
  Rec: TSearchRec;
  Found: Integer;
  Date: TDateTime;
  s:string;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if length(folder)=0 then exit;
  if Folder[Length(folder)] = '\' then
    Delete(Folder, Length(folder), 1);
  Found  := FindFirst(Folder, faDirectory, Rec);
  try
    try
    if Found = 0 then
    begin
      Date   := FileDateToDateTime(Rec.Time);
      Result := Date;
    end;
    except
      s:='error';
      form1.Caption:=s;
      //raise;
    end;
  finally
    FindClose(Rec);
  end;
end;

{ Sets the time for both files and directories }
{ for NT }

function NT_SetDateTime(FileName: string; dtCreation, dtLastAccessTime, dtLastWriteTime: TDateTime): Boolean;
// by Nicholas Robinson
var
  hDir: THandle;
  ftCreation: TFiletime;
  ftLastAccessTime: TFiletime;
  ftLastWriteTime: TFiletime;

  function DTtoFT(dt: TDateTime): TFiletime;
  var
    dwft: DWORD;
    ft: TFiletime;
  begin
    dwft := DateTimeToFileDate(dt);
    DosDateTimeToFileTime(LongRec(dwft).Hi, LongRec(dwft).Lo, ft);
    LocalFileTimeToFileTime(ft, Result);
  end;

begin
  hDir := CreateFile(PChar(FileName),
                     GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
                     0,
                     nil,
                     OPEN_EXISTING,
                     FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                     0);
  if hDir <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then 
  begin
    try
      ftCreation       := DTtoFT(dtCreation);
      ftLastAccessTime := DTtoFT(dtLastAccessTime);
      ftLastWriteTime  := DTtoFT(dtLastWriteTime);
      Result := SetFileTime(hDir, @ftCreation, @ftLastAccessTime, @ftLastWriteTime);
    finally
      CloseHandle(hDir);
    end;
  end
  else
    Result := False;
end;

procedure getdir(dir1:string);
var sr:tsearchrec;
    sr2:tsearchrec;
    dtt,lastdate:tdatetime;
begin
  if Length(dir1)=0 then exit;
  if dir1[Length(dir1)] = '\' then
    Delete(dir1, Length(dir1), 1);
  if not directoryexists(dir1) then
    begin
    Form1.memo1.Lines.Add('dir "'+dir1+'" not exists');
    exit;
    end;
  if FindFirst(dir1+'\*.*',faDirectory,sr)<>0 then exit;
    repeat
    if sr.Attr and fadirectory=0 then continue;
    if (sr.Name='.') or (sr.Name='..') then continue;
    Form1.memo1.Lines.Add(dir1+'\'+sr.Name+'\');
    if sr.Attr and fadirectory=fadirectory then getdir(dir1+'\'+sr.name);
    lastdate:=0;
    if FindFirst(dir1+'\'+sr.name+'\*.*',faanyfile,sr2)<>0 then continue;
      repeat
      if (sr2.Name='.') or (sr2.Name='..') then continue;
      dtt:=getfolderdate(dir1+'\'+sr.name+'\'+sr2.Name);
      if lastdate=0 then lastdate:=dtt;
      if (lastdate<>0) and (dtt>lastdate) then lastdate:=dtt;
      Form1.memo1.Lines.Add('     '+sr2.Name+' '+datetimetostr(dtt));
      until findnext(sr2)<>0;
    findclose(sr2);
    Form1.memo1.Lines.Add('last date: '+datetimetostr(lastdate));
    if lastdate=0 then
       //lastdate:=getfolderdate(dir1+'\'+sr.name);
       continue;
    //NT_SetDateTime(dir1+'\'+sr.Name,lastdate,lastdate,lastdate);
    until FindNext(sr)<>0;
  FindClose(sr);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var dir1:string;
date:tdatetime;
begin
  dir1:=edit1.text;
  getdir(dir1);
end;

end.
```

The dir has wrong date, for example, year 1678 (it was the result of another mistake)

Directory structure:

```
d:\test
d:\test\a
d:\test\a\1
d:\test\a\2 <wrong date here>
d:\test\a\3
d:\test\b
d:\test\b\1
d:\test\b\2
d:\test\b\3
```

It gives an error: EConvertError with message 'Invalid argument to date encode'

If I uncomment the lines, the error does not occur and exception is not executed

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19FLQPbt53A

EDIT: Not duplicate. Not always reproducible on Delphi 7, on newer versions hard to reproduce. Probably a IDE bug.

Comment: Do you get the exception only while running the project inside the IDE/Debugger or even when running stand alone?

Comment: [`TDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TDateTime) only supports dates from 1899-12-30, that's why the conversion fails (and different date/time types exist). When using `try ... except` an exception is _handled_ - does it really not execute those two lines that access `rec.time` as if it would be a `TDateTime` although it isn't?

Comment: @AmigoJack `TDateTime` accepts negative values (as stated in your link), so it can represent dates before 1899-12-30.

Comment: `It gives an error:`  What does that mean?  Where did you see this error?  In a dialog box?  What other words were on it?

Comment: Also the `.Time` field in [`TSearchRec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TSearchRec) is deprecated.  You should use the `.TimeStamp` property instead.

Comment: FYI [ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter).

Comment: It's not perfectly obvious that this is your problem, but given that it's likely : [Still get error popup inside try…except](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5735719/327083)

Comment: [How do I let Delphi know I've already handled an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1234950/327083)

Comment: With no further input from OP, I think it's safe to make an assumption here.

Comment: not always reproducible. not duplicate. TQuery and ApplyUpdates are competely different things.

Comment: @J... `Project Project1.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message 'Invalid argument to date encode'.`, then dialog box in the application itself, if you continue.       `s:=datetimetostr(rec.time);` - this is a mistake, but this line is not executed. it could be `form1.caption:='error';` but caption is never changed.

Comment: Reproducible on Delphi 7, regardless of whether it is run under debugger or executable.

Comment: The same project may or may not cause an error at different times.

Comment: @J... Not a duplicate!

Comment: @J... This question: "exception NOT catching". That question: "still GET popup error". What relation? Also, that question about databases. I'm not getting a popup error and not execution in "except" statement.

Comment: @jsmith It's highly doubtful what you're experiencing is a compiler bug.  Unless you can produce a [mcve] or provide any additional information, there's nothing we can do to help.  What you say happens is not reproduced when we do the same thing - so something you are doing is different.  Without a [mcve], we have no idea what that is.  Suggest you install MadExcept and spend some time debugging.

Comment: What is obvious is that you're performing a dubious `DateTimeToStr` call on a value that, at this point, has already thrown an exception attempting to convert it to string, and you're making this call *inside the except block*, meaning that if it also throws an exception then you will still have an unhandled exception.  You have provided no debugging details for us, so we have to guess about what you're doing.  Feel free to add some more information like line numbers where the exception is thrown, a stack trace, etc.  Anything you can tell us can help, and you haven't told us much.

Comment: In fact, the entire `s:=datetimetostr(rec.time);` call is doomed to fail because `rec.time` is not the correct format for `datetimetostr`, so this is clearly a mistake.  You seem to already know this because you're using `FileDateToDateTime` (which is the correct method) in the first place.  So don't explode your except block by doing something you know is wrong and that's failed already.

Comment: @J... video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19FLQPbt53A

full code:
https://pastebin.com/Aa5SUW99

directory structure:
https://pastebin.com/dD60pazB

Comment: @jsmith That's not how it works.  Code goes in the question.

Comment: @J... Already corrected (added to the question the same day). Thought you at least saw it, but no changes.