# Delphi XE4 - Exception with IdHTTP in function

Tags: delphi

Something is not working right here and I wonder if somebody could see the error in the code below.

```
function CheckUrl(url: String): Boolean;
var
  sResp: String;
begin
  Result := False;      
  try
    sResp := IdHTTP1.Get(url);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do Result := False;
    on E: EIdConnClosedGracefully do Result := False;
    on E: EIdSocketError do Result := False;
    on E: EIdException do Result := False;
    on E: Exception do Result := False;
  end;
  if IdHTTP1.ResponseCode = 200 then Result := True;
end;
```

I use this function in OnShow event of the main form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  urlOk: boolean;
begin
  //code1
  if not CheckURL(Url) then 
    begin
      //code2
    end;
  //some code here
end;
```

The problem occurs when internet connection is not available. Even if I used try-except method in CheckUrl function, and handled all exceptions, the CheckUrl function does not return False if exception happens and code2 is not executed.
Maybe someone will see the mistake and point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried moving the If statement inside the Try..Except block?

Comment: The clauses other than `on E: Exception do Result := False;` serve no purpose. `Exception` covers all the others.

Comment: David: I've tried with all 5 exceptions all together, with Exception only, with others taken as individual and ... no difference. I do not receive de SocketError AV, but function returns no value ...
Andy: I've tried, no success.
It is very strange this is not working, because I use try-except in many places and everywhere is working as it should.

Comment: I'm not talking about trial and error. I'm telling you that the `Exception` case covers all the others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I let Delphi know I've already handled an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234950/how-do-i-let-delphi-know-ive-already-handled-an-exception)

Comment: Are you *sure* the function doesn't return False? Or have you just not allowed your program to continue running after the debugger interrupted it to tell you that an exception occurred?

Answer (score 4):

You can greatly simplify your function to the following:

```
function CheckUrl(url: String): Boolean;
begin
  try
    // using AResponseContent=nil to discard any data received so as not to waste any memory storing it temporarily...
    IdHTTP1.Get(url, TStream(nil));
    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function CheckUrl(url: String): Boolean;
begin
  try
    IdHTTP1.Head(url);
    Result := True;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

If that still does not return the expected result then something is seriously wrong with your project or IDE installation.